# Quando usar Dim e quando usar Set?

Tags: vba, variáveis

Quais são as diferenças entre o `Dim` e o `Set`? Quando usar cada um?

---

Contexto 1

```
Dim minhaString as String
minhaString = "Olá!"
```

Contexto 2

```
Set minhaString = "Olá!"
```

Comment: Poderia elaborar melhor a sua pergunta? No contexto do VBA são comandos distintos. "Set" tem a ver com atribuição de variável. "Dim" tem a ver com escopo de uso da variável.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dim` e `Set` são palavras reservadas de algumas linguagens como Visual Basic, VBScript e VBA (*Visual Basic for Applications*).

A palavra reservada `Dim` é utilizada para declarar uma variável. Já a palavra `Set` é utilizada para atribuir uma referência de um objeto a uma variável.

Exemplos em VBScript:

```
Dim numero
numero = 2

Dim xlApp
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Note que quando estamos lidando com objetos em VBScript e VBA é necessário utilizar a palavra `Set` antes da variável. Isso acontece, pois estamos guardando na variável a referência de um objeto. Por outro lado, quando estamos lidando com números, string, booleanos isso não é necessário. Por causa disso, a variável `numero` acima recebeu o valor `2` sem a necessidade da palavra reservada `Set`.

Portanto, não é o caso de utilizar `Dim` ou `Set` como sugerido da pergunta. São palavras reservadas para usos distintos. Uma para declarar (`Dim`) outra para atribuir (`Set`).

Existe outro uso para a palavra Set que é na definição de propriedades de uma classe, entretanto, creio que isso foge ao escopo da pergunta, já que foi questionada a relação entre Dim e Set.